# Server-side GTM billing quota exceeded

Tags: google-tag-manager, server-side

I would like to try server-side GTM. So I did the process of creating a server GTM on GCP. Automatically provision tagging  server was failed.
Error Reported: Google Cloud platform billing quota exceeded. So I tried Manually provision tagging server which passed me without problems.
I have several projects running in GCP .  And I have set up a billing account which is cleared and used every month .
What exactly is the problem and how to set up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem in case you are already a user of GCP and exceeded the free tier limit. You can have only one Free testing sGTM instance on one account.

If you already used the Free tier or want to create one more testing server there is no possibility to do this for free and automatically.

For manual server provisioning you can follow [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/serverside/script-user-guide)

Also as an option I can recommend to try Stape as much cheaper and easier to setup alternative for GTM Server Side hosting. There you can create infinity free servers for sGTM on one account.

For example you can follow this article on how to setup free server for Server Side GTM:
https://stape.io/how-to-set-up-google-tag-manager-server-side-container/

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to us and the problem is a very basic one. Apparently by default one billing account in GCP can be tied to 5 projects (who knew :) ). You're probably at that limit and that's what Google Tag Manager interface means by "Google Cloud platform billing quota exceeded" --> you're trying to add the 6th project to that account.

Two options comes to mind to solve that:

1. Create a new billing account (with the same credit card if you want) and tie your new server project to that account
2. Request for a quota increase from [here](https://support.google.com/code/contact/billing_quota_increase) so your billing account is able to handle more projects

Alternatively you can do 1, then do 2, and when your request is approved change the billing account of the project that contains your GTM server.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and this is what I'm suggesting:

1. ask for increasing quota for current billing account, if not successful:
2. create new billing account (but be very careful).

Why not the other way? Why not creating first new billing account if you are allowed to do this? I did it, and attached new project to the account, and redirected domain to the project, and everything was fine, but after some time Google send me message like this:

> There is some suspicious activity related to your billing accounts, your all accounts are now suspended, your projects are suspended, your domains returns 404. Send us photos of documents which will allow us to verify your accounts (credit cards, ID, payments confirmations). We will check somedays. Till then you can't do anything, you can't close project, accounts, remap domains, nothing! Have a nice day!

If you every tried to contact Google in person, you know how big your problem is. Good luck!

ps. I never found out what the suspicious activity was (probably just creating new billing account).